# android: layout just dialog box

Tags: android, android-layout, background, dialog

i have layout like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/olDEn.jpg

[image]

and my script in `mainActivity`:

```
onCreate( . . . ){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        login();            

}

private void login(){

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.login_password, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

     userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.login);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {



          })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();                



            }
          });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

layout  background(splash screen) in `activity_main.xml`, and dialog box `login_password.xml`

How to remove background(splash screen in image), i want to the layout just dialog box (password). Can i do that?

Comment: can you post a picture what you would look like to look.

Comment: yes, but i don't know why can't show . .

Comment: I don't see where the problem is. The splash screen is not a layout background, it is the activity itself. The activity that hosts your dialog. If you want to remove it then change the `activity_main.xml` file

Comment: wait, i will post a picture

Comment: @virho where is the resulting image?

Comment: @Miro: yes, i know. So, i want to layout activity just dialog box. No full screen, just dialog box. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a new activity for dialog, and make the activity transparent and show the dialog on that new activity. The code to transparent activity is a new style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tranparent dialog Activity by using this line.

just put a line in AndroidManifest.xml, where you define your activity in manifest.

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"